# Is Parallel For Each Supported only in Mule 4.2 Run Time?

Tags: mule

I am currently developing Mule application using 4.1.5 Run Time. I have the requirement to use parallel foreach . Is it supported only in 4.2.1? If not supported in 4.1.5. Is there any batch provided for the run time to support in 4.1.5?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/parallel-foreach-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel foreach was indeed introduced in Mule 4.2.0 and hence, cannot be used in 4.1.5. There is no patch available as it is a new feature and not a bug fix.

Comment: Is there any other equivalent way to do the same in Mule 4.1.5 Run Time?

Comment: It really depends on your use case, why was parallel foreach considered in the first place?

Comment: I was searching for each and mule docs shown me parallel for each .My use case is to make the rest api call for array of product number and aggregate the response as request for another api. I don't want to do it in sequence since it affects performance

Comment: Why not use a scatter gather instead then? https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/scatter-gather-concept

Comment: I am using the scatter gather for other use case. I am really not sure how to do achieve this use case in Scatter gather (i get 'n' number of productId as an input . I need to make HTTP call 'n' times).